# in Delphi application.OnMessage does not receive WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST in windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi

I am using application.OnMessage to prevent keyboard layout change (writing text other than English) in some controls. But on Win7/Win10 message WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST is never received. On windows XP it works fine. 
Is there another way to catch and prevent user from switching the input language?

Comment: Might be by design (ie MS decided not to send this message in new OSes) - when user wants to change kb layout, its not some thirdparty software's right to prevent that. Your program should validate the input and reject it if it is not valid.

Comment: Yes, if so, there is no other way, but nothing updated about this in MSDN.... But I see posts from C++ programmers, who catch this message in Win10...

Comment: Michael S. Kaplan wrote about this, and why it happens. If you Google "What broke the input language messages?" you will find the reference. I think it refers to how to solve it too.

Comment: Starting from Windows 7 forward  (perhaps also in Vista) the keyboard input language is no longer globl setting but it can be defined or changed for each separate application. Therefore I asume the underlying messages that are being sent have also changed

Comment: Yes, I found this article http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Handling_Input_Language_Change_Message

Comment: This is a *sent* message, Application.OnMessage should never work at all.

Comment: Note that `CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` is not new in Berlin, it has been in the VCL for a long time. You can catch `CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` at the Application level by using `Application.HookMainWindow()`.  Or you can add a `CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message handler to your individual Form(s) and/or specific controls as needed.

Comment: @sertac WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST is documented as being posted. Oh, but then the docs say *A window receives this message through its WindowProc function*. So you are surely right. In which case the asker should investigate who is posting this message since it is not the system.

Comment: @David - Yeah, MS should decide the distinction of *posted* and *sent*. I tend to the accept the distinction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#routing) *The system posts a message to a thread's message queue by filling an MSG structure and then copying it to the message queue.* vs. *Nonqueued messages are sent immediately to the destination window procedure, bypassing the system message queue and thread message queue.*. Documentation of this specific message stresses that you don't have to return from the message. I guess that's what makes it *posted* here.

Comment: .. also note, where the mechanics of 'WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST' explained ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688135.aspx#eve)), it's being referred to as *sent*.